# Why is the Rust random number generator slower with multiple instances running?

Tags: performance, rust, shared-memory

I am doing some random number generation for my [Lotto Simulation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116399/lotto-simulator) and was wondering why would it be MUCH slower when running multiple instances?

I am running this program under Ubuntu 15.04 (linux kernel 4.2). `rustc 1.7.0-nightly (d5e229057 2016-01-04)`

Overall CPU utilization is about 45% during these tests but each individual thread is taking up 100% of that thread.

Here is my script I am using to start multiple instances at the same time.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pkill lotto_sim

for _ in `seq 1 14`;
do
    ./lotto_sim 15000000 1>> /var/log/syslog &
done
```

Output:

```
Took PT38.701900316S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
Took PT39.193917241S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
Took PT39.412279484S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
Took PT39.492940352S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
Took PT39.715433024S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
Took PT39.726609237S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
Took PT39.884151996S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
Took PT40.025874106S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
Took PT40.088332517S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
Took PT40.112601899S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
Took PT40.205958636S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
Took PT40.227956170S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
Took PT40.393753486S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
Took PT40.465173616S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
```

However, a single run gives this output:

```
$ ./lotto_sim 15000000
Took PT9.860698141S seconds to generate 15000000 random tickets
```

My understanding is that each process has it's own memory and doesn't share anything. Correct?

Here is the relevant code:

```
extern crate rand;
extern crate itertools;
extern crate time;

use std::env;

use rand::{Rng, Rand};
use itertools::Itertools;
use time::PreciseTime;

struct Ticket {
    whites: Vec<u8>,
    power_ball: u8,
    is_power_play: bool,
}

const POWER_PLAY_PERCENTAGE: u8 = 15;
const WHITE_MIN: u8 = 1;
const WHITE_MAX: u8 = 69;
const POWER_BALL_MIN: u8 = 1;
const POWER_BALL_MAX: u8 = 26;

impl Rand for Ticket {
    fn rand<R: Rng>(rng: &mut R) -> Self {
        let pp_guess = rng.gen_range(0, 100);
        let pp_value = pp_guess < POWER_PLAY_PERCENTAGE;

        let mut whites_vec: Vec<_> = (0..).map(|_| rng.gen_range(WHITE_MIN, WHITE_MAX + 1))
                                          .unique().take(5).collect();
        whites_vec.sort();

        let pb_value = rng.gen_range(POWER_BALL_MIN, POWER_BALL_MAX + 1);
        Ticket { whites: whites_vec, power_ball: pb_value, is_power_play: pp_value}
    }
}

fn gen_test(num_tickets: i64) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let _: Vec<_> = rng.gen_iter::<Ticket>()
            .take(num_tickets as usize)
            .collect();
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
    let num_tickets: i64 = args[1].parse::<i64>().unwrap();

    let start = PreciseTime::now();
    gen_test(num_tickets);
    let end = PreciseTime::now();

    println!("Took {} seconds to generate {} random tickets", start.to(end), num_tickets);

}
```

Edit:

Maybe a better question would be how do I debug and figure this out? Where would I look within the program or within my OS to find the performance hindrances? I am new to Rust and lower level programming like this that relies so heavily on the OS.

Comment: Well, you're running 14 instances in parallel, so each taking 4 times as long still generates ~3 times more tickets per second.

Comment: *why would it be MUCH slower when running multiple instances?*  Why?  Because whatever it's doing doesn't scale, or you're bound by some resource limit such as CPU cycles.  Without detailed information, all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: http://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/index.html section about blocking

Comment: @keltar reading the [section I think you mean](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/index.html#cryptographic-security) (note you can link to a specific header of the docs), it says that a Linux system past kernel 3.17 is unlikely to block unless the system has recently been booted. Do you suspect that is the case here?

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase it. `urandom` isn't instantly-fast. It takes time to generate random number, and by time I mean CPU cycles. Program have no designated sleeps or blocks, so it have no reason to not occupy full CPU, and if it doesn't - it probably means `urandom` can work only on one CPU core (which makes sense, but cannot verify for now). Since it is kernel call it will not be counted as your program CPU load, but as system time.

Comment: @electrometro what does it even mean and how it reflects "I am only hitting about 45% core load"?

Comment: @electrometro which is exactly what I meant when I said urandom doesn't go parallel, or at least not infinitely. Look at e.g. http://drsnyder.us/2014/04/16/linux-dev-urandom-and-concurrency.html

Comment: @keltar Rust doesn't *just* ask `/dev/urandom` for bits. [`OsRng`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rand/blob/8feb9df678990f91c39759f62c05f5ad5a6a78c8/src/os.rs) uses `getrandom` or `/dev/urandom`, which then seeds [`StdRng`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rand/blob/8feb9df678990f91c39759f62c05f5ad5a6a78c8/src/lib.rs#L783-L798) which is [kept in TLS](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rand/blob/8feb9df678990f91c39759f62c05f5ad5a6a78c8/src/lib.rs#L873) and [reseeded every 32K](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rand/blob/8feb9df678990f91c39759f62c05f5ad5a6a78c8/src/lib.rs#L851).

Comment: `.unique()` is using a `HashSet` too, so that's another thing hitting `OsRng` regularly.

Comment: What is the problem? How does your result differ from your expectations?

Comment: @sellibitze maybe my expectations are skewed but I would expect it to be almost linear in scaling. I would expect running multiple of the same code wouldn't make each one individually slow down unless I was maxing out some sort of hardware (CPU, Memory, Disk).

Comment: What level of concurrency does your hardware support? If your hardware concurrency is 4 (being able to run 4 threads concurrently) your time measurements are exactly what I would expect.

Comment: @sellibitze Yes, as I have stated I am NOT hitting my maximum amount of CPU threads/cores or percent utilization on either. Each thread used (14 of them in this case) is at 100%. But I have many more available.